# Applying toLocaleString to all dynamic textboxes with a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Working on an ASP.NET website. I have a page where there are alot of dynamically created textboxes. In addition to these textboxes I link dynamic javascript calculations to certain textboxes as well. This is all database driven. For example....

```
(pseudo-code)
textbox1 = "10"
textbox2 = "4"
textbox3 = textbox 1 + textbox 2 (displays "14")
```

All of the textboxes are working great, dynamically calculating correctly, etc.... BUT, I need to format them with commas, if applicable. All of these dynamic textboxes have a css class of 'dynamic_control'.

Question: I would like to autoformat numbers > 999 with commas. (AFTER any calculations are finalized.) So, what I did was this...

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            calculateAllTextboxValues();
            $('.dynamic_control').toLocaleString('en-US');
        });
```

The second line I wanted to apply toLocaleString to all the dynamically created textboxes, by referencing their class. But, for some reason it's not working. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each` to iterate over all the text boxes with the `dynamic_control` class. For each one, the text must be converted to numeric value before using `toLocaleString`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    calculateAllTextboxValues();
    $('.dynamic_control').each(function () {
        var intValue = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        if (!isNaN(intValue)) {
            $(this).val(intValue.toLocaleString('en-US'));
        }
    });
});
```